# redux-observable wont be execute after catchError

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am using redux-observable in my angular project. I have an `updateNode` function in my epics with `catchError` handling. I dispatch action `DB_UPDATE_NODE` many times and everything work well. However the time action execute `catchError` when I dispatch that action again, `updateNode` function wont be called any more.

```
public updateNode(action$: Observable<IScenarioNodesAction>, store: Store<IAppState>) {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(ScenarioNodeActionType.DB_UPDATE_NODE),
    flatMap((action) => {
     return  this._scenarioNodeService.update(action.payload.botId);
    }),
    flatMap(data => [
      this._scenarioNodeAction.updateNode(data),
    ]),
    catchError((error) => { 
      return Observable.of(this._commonAction.showError(error));
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to catch the error on the service's stream.

```
flatMap((action) => {
  return this._scenarioNodeService.update(action.payload.botId)
             .pipe(catchError(...)) ;
})
```

See the [docs](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/ErrorHandling.html) for more information.

> Here we placed the catchError() inside our mergeMap(), but after our AJAX call; this is important because if we let the error reach the action$.pipe(), it will terminate it and no longer listen for new actions.

Comment: Thanks! but I faced with another error says I can not set value on setter :(

Comment: I was wrong, you have to do this on the service call, I didn't see the second flatmap. See the updated answer

Comment: I did on service but no result.

Answer (score 0):

If your observable returns an errors it stops the observer from getting new events.

Please add to catchError something like:

```
  public updateNode(action$: Observable<IScenarioNodesAction>, store: Store<IAppState>){
    return action$.pipe(
      ofType(ScenarioNodeActionType.DB_UPDATE_NODE),
      flatMap((action) => {
       return  this._scenarioNodeService.update(action.payload.botId);
      }),
        flatMap(data => [
          this._scenarioNodeAction.updateNode(data),
        ]) ,
        catchError((error) => { 
              retryWhen((errors) => {
               return errors
                .pipe(delay(1000), take(1))
                .concat(Observable.throw(`Error`));
            },
        ),
      })
    );

  }
```

What the above does it waits a second `delay(1000)` and retries an amount of times `take(1)`. If the error persists it throws error `.concat(Observable.throw('Error'))`. In your case you just call `showError` and `drop` the connection.

Comment: Thanks! I have added to catch error but it's same happened again. Not sure but could you please show me how would my code when I add your code? Maybe I am wrong!

Comment: Thanks! I have changed but I have type error. `Type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<{}>>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.`